# Flutter: Changing Pages within a Tab of a TabBar

Tags: flutter, navigation, tabs

what is the most straight-forward way of dynamically changing the types of widgets displayed within the same Tab of a TabBarView, after pressing a button?

I dont want to completely move to a new page with a Navigator, because I want to keep the TabBar and stay in the same Tab, but replace the widgets that are displayed within that Tab.

Thank you to any helpers :)

Answer (score 0):

The TabBar widget has a controller that handles tab switching internally without the need for a navigator.

```
...
class Widget extends StatefulWidget {
  const Widget({super.key});

  @override
  State<Widget> createState() => WidgetState();
}

class WidgetState extends extends State<Widget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

    late TabController _tabController;
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this); //length is the number of desired tabs
    }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                bottom: TabBar(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    tabs: [
                        Tab(
                            text: 'Tab 1', 
                        ),
                        Tab(
                            text: 'Tab 2',
                        ),
                    ],
                )
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                    Widget2(),
                    Widget3()
                ],
            ),
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to simply avoid to use Navigator and display other widgets when the Tab on the TabBar where Tapped you can [follow the example given on the Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjw7aqkBhDPARIsAKGa0oK_cnzkITXGaLaO-hPpGBXAsQVJReGEzPRIlCVzesC4M1Q4LQzUaZsaArf0EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

If you pay attention, the body content on the first example is displayed according to the index of the TabBar Icon were Tapped. If you Tap the first Icon, it will show the first content on the TabBarView children.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('TabBar Sample'),
    bottom: TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      tabs: const <Widget>[
        Tab(
          icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access_sharp),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  body: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: const <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Text("It's rainy here"),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text("It's cloudy here"),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text("It's sunny here"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Sorry if i didn't explain my problem properly. The thing is, I don't want to switch tabs in this instance. I just want to change the content of the TabBarView within the current tab, after for example a button is pressed....so essentially replacing the childwidget of the TabBarView with another one. Is there a way to replace widgets dynamically or transition between widgets?

Comment: Did you try to execute the first example on the doc? The behavior appears to do exactly what you want, i think. I really dont know if I misunderstood the behavior you want to get.

Comment: It's ok, I will just use an extra tab to display what is needed. Originally I wanted to put both into one single tab and allow the user to switch between different views within one and the same tab, but in the end thats probably just more confusing, so I will just use 2 seperate tabs. Thank you for your effort though :)